# Instagram client disabled for violating policies, 2018

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api, privacy-policy

I am developing scoring tools for Instagram.

The use case: user sharing his content with the service, service is providing score and some clues to the user, user's choice is to share his score with public or not. Only basic permissions were requested.

About a month ago, I submitted the production-ready web service for review, however it was disabled with resolution:

*"This client was disabled for violating the Instagram Platform Policies."*

I double checked with the policies, and didn't find anything that the service does not comply with.

The information provided for the Instagram review (if it may help):

- website - https://hype.technology
- privacy policy - https://hype.technology/privacy
- screencast - https://hype.technology/static/hype.technology_Screencast.mov

Why could this happen?
Is the conclusion valid?
Is there any way to fix this?

Please let me know if you been in same situation and how you resolved it.

P.S. I'd love to have a support from Instagram, however no one seem ever got relevant info from them.